# Vuejs and vue-socketio: how to pass socket instance to components

Tags: javascript, architecture, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to use Vuejs together with the [Vue-Socket.io plugin](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io) and have a question regarding the correct way of passing the socket between components.

Ideally I want to use only one socket in my whole app, so I want to instantiate the socket in the root instance and then pass it down to the components that need it as a 'prop'. Is that the correct way of doing it?

If so, what am I doing wrong? The error I receive is `TypeError: this.socket.emit is not a function` so I am probably not passing the socket object correctly.

The component using the socket has the following script

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'top',
    props: ['socket'],
    data () {
      return {
        Title: 'My Title'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      button_click: function (val) {
        // This should emit something to the socketio server
        console.log('clicking a button')
        this.socket.emit('vuejs_inc', val)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

My initialization in the root component looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://127.0.0.1:5000')
Vue.config.productionTip = false
/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App socket="this.$socket"/>',
  components: {App},
  sockets: {
    connect: function () {
      console.log('Vuejs socket connected.')
    },
    from_server: function (val) {
      console.log('Data from server received: ' + val)
    }
  }
})
```

And App then passes the socket via

```
<top socket="this.socket"></top>
```

NB: I know that I could also either put the socket instantiation into the component that needs it (in this case: top), or I could access the socket object from the root component via `this.$root.$socket`, but I don't want to do either, because

- As stated above, I might want to use the socket in other components
- I don't just want to assume a socket object is there in the root instance

In essence, I want to do it right from an architectural standpoint.

Comment: I passed the socket instance from the root instance into the App instance via `this.$socket`, so shouldn't I be able to just pass `this.socket` from App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to pass anything. The Vue-Socket.io plugin [makes the socket available](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/blob/d3c8d11f9e370cbd72502167af4e10f204ce02fe/src/Main.js#L12) on *every* component (and Vue) via `this.$socket`.

I think your code would work except for the fact that you do not appear to be *binding* the socket.

```
<top socket="this.socket"></top>
```

Should be

```
<top :socket="socket"></top>
```

The first line above will just set socket to the string "this.socket". The second will set the property to the result of the expression, `this.socket`.

You would also need to change the template for the Vue:

```
<App :socket="$socket"/>
```

Comment: But is that also architecturally the right way to use it? I think being declarative in a component defintion (in terms of what is expected to be there) is a good thing, which is why I wanted to explicitly pass the socket instance.

Comment: @random_error It's the same way Vuex and VueRouter work (implementing a $store and $router property respectively) and those are official plugins. You could make a strong argument that it is the "right way". An alternative would be to use the plugins integration with Vuex (if you are using it) and just dispatch actions to send/receive messages.

Comment: Point taken, but let's say I wanted to reuse my component, or make it clear for other people reusing the component that it expects a socket-io connection, what would be the right way to go about that then? The vuex $store and the VueRouter come with Vue, so they might be expected to be there, but the socketio plugin is not necessarily there. I might be overthinking this, as I'm quite new to Vue, I'm just trying to implement a clear and concise design.

Comment: @random_error I don't think you're wrong to think about those issues. It personally never made a lot of sense to me that Vuex was embedded in every component because it necessarily ties your component to Vuex. That's why libs like [vue-connect](https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-connect) exist. However, the Vue powers that be definitely seem to push this approach for plugins and the community is embracing it. That said, I don't think you're taking the wrong approach, I just think it may be premature. If/when you need to you can refactor.

Comment: @random_error Also, I noted a possible error in the code. You might try that change.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I'll accept your answer. :)

Comment: And thanks for your edit, it actually works if I bind the socket variable correctly, which I didn't before, you're right!

Comment: `this.$socket.emit('socketExperiment', { message: 'Hello!' })` in "[name_of_application]/src/router/index.js" triggers an error:  "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit')"